Android Application crashes due to late init variable Fregment Context not been initialized
I am working with the android application which sometimes gives the late init fragment context not initialized issue when user opens the dialog in application. Following is the sample code segment how we trigger the dialog box from a ViewModel method.
fun onUndo() {
        ConfirmDialog()
            .setTitle(getViewContext().getString(R.string.TITLE_TEXT))// this also access getViewContext but working without any exception
            .setMessage(String.format(getViewContext().getString(R.string.MESSAGE_TEXT),replenList?.replenType))
            .showDialog(getViewContext()) {
                if(it == ConfirmDialog.EVENT_YES) {
                    // do the confirm logic and if there is exception, or known error following method code is used to display error in bottom (we call it status bar)
                                if (error is DomainException) {
                                    selectInputText.postValue(true)
                                    DomainEventListener.publish(
                                        DomainEvent(
                                            getViewContext().getString(R.string.error), // place we see exception occures
                                            getViewContext().getString(getStringResourceIdByName(error.getStatusCode())),
                                            DomainEventType.ERROR)
                                    )
                                }
                } else {
                    // else part if user does not confirm
                    DomainEventListener.publish(
                        DomainEvent(
                            "",
                            getViewContext().getString(R.string.INFO_UNDO_CANCELED), // place where we see exception.
                            DomainEventType.INFO)
                    )
                }
            }
    }

as mentioned in the code by comment the exception occurs when it tries to access the getViewContext method in the ViewModel.

NOTE: getViewContext workes fine in the 3rd line when we set title, error only occurs when it tries to reach getViewContext in within the showDialog when we tried to pass it to the DomainEventListner.

FURTHER EXPLANATION
The project is developed with MVVM architecture (little diverted to MVVM in some context). There is a BaseFragment class and BaseViewModel class use as a parent class for each Fragment and ViewModel classes and in the BaseViewModel class getViewContext() method implemented as follows.
fun getViewContext(): FragmentActivity {
        if (viewContext != null) {
            return viewContext as FragmentActivity
        }
        return fragmentContext
    }

viewContext is declare as private var viewContext: Any? = null; and private var viewContext: Any? = null; within the BaseViewModel class scope. and we have setViewContext method as follows to set the view contex,
fun setViewContext(viewContext: FragmentActivity) {
        this.viewContext = viewContext
    }

and for each fragment onCreateView method it will call setViewContext method like this,
viewModel.setViewContext(requireActivity())

to set the view Context.
So I have 2 questions.

What would be the best way to fix this issue, the best practice to implement so we do not face this issue further.
Since, this project already implemented with this mechanism, what would be the easiest way to resolve whit issue without lot of impact to the existing code base.

Thanks in advance.

Viewmodels should only use application context (ie. AndroidViewModel), if they hold Activity reference it's a leak and violation of MVVM.

@Pawel, the memory leaks are the key concern. ViewModel doesn't necessarily have to be used specifically for the MVVM architecture. A Google engineer who worked on it went on Reddit and said they did not intend for the name to suggest a recommended architecture, but "naming things is hard".


What would be the best way to fix this issue, the best practice to implement so we do not face this issue further.

Remove the viewContext reference from the ViewModel. It should have no knowledge of the environment it's running in.
Don't show a confirmation dialog from a ViewModel - that is a UI operation that should be done by the View (the V in MVVM, not the Android "View"). The ViewModel should be handling UI input to trigger business logic and reporting back the current state of the UI, not showing dialogs, running animations, doing navigation, or other UI tasks.
Anything you think you need a Context for (like resources) can be abstracted out. For example, instead of passing a Context to a VieModel so it can get a string, pass something like a StringProvider interface that can do stringProvider.getString(R.string.my_string). The implementation uses Context to actually get the string, but the ViewModel has no knowledge or dependency on it.

Since, this project already implemented with this mechanism, what would be the easiest way to resolve whit issue without lot of impact to the existing code base.

You said: "for each fragment onCreateView method it will call setViewContext method". If that's the case then clearly you are calling undo before that. So identify where that is getting called and ensure it's getting called after you set the context.
Alternatively you could try setting the view context in onCreate which is called before onCreateView.

EDIT: If it works before you show the dialog but crashes after, then use the context before you show the dialog to get the strings you need to eliminate the need to use the context after.
fun undo() {
   val cachedString = contextThatIsValidNow.getString(...)
   ...
   showDialog(...) {
       // use cachedString instead of getContext() that crashes
   }
}


Thank you for the answer and I agree with the first part and this is not following proper MVVM architecture. but as per second fix setViewModel indeed called before onUndo method since it called on fragments onCreateView and it can confirm since my first code segment 3rd line code works fine with getViewContext().getString(R.string.TITLE_TEXT). Only issue comes when we tried the same method within the show dialog confirm event. I am not clear how this is happening.

See update to address your comment.

Avoiding the ViewModel having a reference to the view is not just about proper MVVM architecture.  ViewModel is specifically designed in a way that giving it a reference to the UI views of any kind will literally cause memory leaks. It is not optional to decide whether to allow it to reference UI. (ViewModel is not even designed specifically for MVVM architecture--it just happens to have a name that aligns with it. One of the developers of the ViewModel class from Google explained that on a Reddit post a while back.)
